# file_put_contents won't update HTML file

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, chat

I'm working on a chatroom for my website as something fun for my friend group. I followed a tutorial online that is pretty over my head, but I figured out how to get a login system and how to display the contents of the chat log file live. The issue I'm having is I have no clue how to properly append the data to the chat log file.

There's a main file called `index.php` that is intended to pass the message to `post.php` which saves it to the `log.html` file using `file_put_contents`. The part that seems to flop is that I don't know how to format or properly handle the data once it gets to log.html. Once the message is posted using the submit button, the forum submits properly without browser errors. It just doesn't save itself to log.html like it's supposed to. Here is the current state of the code, and it's also viewable on my website if you care to see it directly

http://keyboardmechanic.com/index.php

**This is `post.php`:**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    $text = $_POST['text'];
     
    $text_message = "<div class='msgln'><span class='chat-time'>".date("g:i A")."</span> <b class='user-name'>".$_SESSION['name']."</b> ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>";
    file_put_contents("log.html", $text_message, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
?>
```

**This is `log.php`:**

```
<div id="chatbox"><?php
if(file_exists("log.html") && filesize("log.html") > 0){
     
    $contents = file_get_contents("log.html");         
    echo $contents;
}
?></div>
```

**Here's the log file `log.html`:**

```
<html>

    <body>
        Test Message
    </body>
    
</html>
```

**Of what's in `index.php`, here's the script that shows the JQuery version I'm using and the logic behind how the messages are handled.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // jQuery Document
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#submitmsg").click(function () {
                    var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
                    $.post("post.php", { text: clientmsg });
                    $("#usermsg").val("");
                    return false;
                });
                
                //If user submits the form
$("#submitmsg").click(function () {
    var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
    $.post("post.php", { text: clientmsg });
    $("#usermsg").val("");
    return false;
});
                
 
                function loadLog() {
                    var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox")[0].scrollHeight - 20; //Scroll height before the request
 
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "log.html",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (html) {
                            $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div
 
                            //Auto-scroll           
                            var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox")[0].scrollHeight - 20; //Scroll height after the request
                            if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
                                $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
                            }   
                        }
                    });
                }
 
                setInterval (loadLog, 2500);
 
                $("#exit").click(function () {
                    var exit = confirm("Are you sure you want to end the session?");
                    if (exit == true) {
                    window.location = "index.php?logout=true";
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I know it isn't ideally presented, but I hope most of what's relevant is visible.

Comment: If you're appending to `log.html`, then you're putting markup after `</html>`. Given how you're including `log.html` within a `<div>`, I don't think you want a full HTML document in there. In fact. I would remove everything from `log.html` other than `<p>Test Message</p>` (or even just start with it empty)

Comment: I had tried that as well, I didn’t get any success unfortunately :/

Comment: Why do you have two click handlers doing the same thing?

Comment: Good question, I probably forgot that I added one